# Javascript pushState, onpopstate - after ~10 states - clicking 5th step (on back button) and it outputs 4th step

Tags: javascript, pushstate, popstate

Code using to pushState

```
        window.history.pushState({"html":r[0],"pageTitle":r[1], 'bread_crumbs': r[2], 'page': r[3], 'parentid': r[4], 'pageid': r[5]},"", h);
```

Code using to check states

```
window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    console.log(e.state.page+'|'+location.href);
```

So let's say I visited 10 pages - when I click page #5, it is displaying good title in browser. But for some strange reason it ouputs page #4.

It works if I click back button, may be you know - Chrome displays all steps once click second mouse button. So here happens that issue.

Thank you.

You can try it here
http://demo.ajax-cart.com/

Click
1. Test category
2. Brands
3. Blog
4. About
5. News

Go with back button to "Our Blog" - you will see "Brands".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

It was

```
            document.title = r[1];
            window.history.pushState({"html":r[0],"pageTitle":r[1], 'bread_crumbs': r[2], 'page': r[3], 'parentid': r[4], 'pageid': r[5]},"", h);
```

But it must be

```
        window.history.pushState({"html":r[0],"pageTitle":r[1], 'bread_crumbs': r[2], 'page': r[3], 'parentid': r[4], 'pageid': r[5]},"", h);
        document.title = r[1];
```